# snakemake RuleException, if run command in CLI, work well; but if run in snakemake, failed;

Tags: snakemake

```
rule bcftools_call:
input:
    fa="data/ucsc.hg19.fasta",
    bam=expand("sorted_reads/{sample}.bam", sample=SAMPLES),
    bai=expand("sorted_reads/{sample}.bam.bai", sample=SAMPLES)
output:
    "calls/all.vcf"
shell:
    "bcftools mpileup -f {input.fa} {input.bam} |"
    " bcftools call -mv - > {output}"
```

when run this rule,  get an Error

```
CalledProcessError in line 37 of/public/home/wangdl/duolin_work_dir/test/snakemake/snakefile.smk:
Command ' set -euo pipefail;  bcftools mpileup -f data/ucsc.hg19.fasta sorted_reads/A.bam sorted_reads/B.bam | bcftools call -mv - > calls/all.vcf ' returned non-zero exit status 1.
```

BUT, if I run this command in CLI; it works well

```
set -euo pipefail;  bcftools mpileup -f data/ucsc.hg19.fasta sorted_reads/A.bam sorted_reads/B.bam | bcftools call -mv - > calls/all.vcf
```

Note: none of --samples-file, --ploidy or --ploidy-file given, assuming all sites are diploid
[mpileup] 2 samples in 2 input files

SO WHY?

Comment: Snakemake requires all commands in a string of piped commands to have exit codes of 0. After you run your CLI test, run echo $? to see the exit code of your command. If it's not 0, you'll have to figure out a workaround (https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/project_info/faq.html#i-don-t-want-snakemake-to-detect-an-error-if-my-shell-command-exits-with-an-exitcode-1-what-can-i-do). If it's zero, then there is something else going on.

Comment: Some background: by convention exit codes of non-zero mean there was an error, but it's not a strictly enforced rule. Some programs use the exit code in a different way. (I run into this occasionally with grep, because it returns an exit code of 1 when there are no matches, even if there are no errors).

Comment: well，I run command "set -euo pipefail;  bcftools mpileup -f data/ucsc.hg19.fasta sorted_reads/A.bam sorted_reads/B.bam | bcftools call -mv - > calls/all.vcf" , then  “echo $?”   it  return 0;

Comment: is there any else possible problems  that I do not know,  how to resovle this problem? or how to get help?

Comment: The next thing I would check is that snakemake and the CLI are using the sameu copy of bcftools. Insert `which bfctools; ` into the command and try it again in both places. It will print the full path to the bfctools program being run.

Comment: It will also help us help you if you can give us the snakemake command you are running and the full snakefile. If  you're snakefile is too big, try to cut it down to the smallest snakefile that will reproduce your error. This might also help you find the problem.

Answer (score 0):

For troubleshooting, try to split the pipe into two commands and see if any of them fails. E.g. something like:

```
shell:
    r"""
    bcftools mpileup -f {input.fa} {input.bam} > {output}.tmp
    bcftools call -mv {output}.tmp > {output}"
    rm {output}.tmp
    """"
```